# Counting the number of arrows

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am working on my first project in OpenCV.
I need to find all the arrows in the [image: image]] and save the orientation in a list.

I used template matching to find all the arrows. That works since all the arrows are similar to each other. I formed rectangle box around each arrow. But when I try to count these  rectangles it does not give a result that I expected. I cannot figure out what is happening.

Template:[image: left_to_right_arrow]
           [image: right_to_left_arrow]

```
    image = cv2.imread('input.png')
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#Converted to grayscale

    ###read the templates
    right = cv2.imread('Images/arrow_right.png',0)
    wr, hr = right.shape[::-1]
    left=cv2.imread('Images/arrow_left.png',0)
    wl, hl = left.shape[::-1]
    slf=cv2.imread('Images/self_arrow.jpg',0)
    ws, hs = slf.shape[::-1]

    ###Template Matching
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,right,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    res1= cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,left,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    res2= cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,slf,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    ###To get multiple instances set a threshold
    threshold = 0.85
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    loc1=np.where(res1 >= threshold)
    loc2 = np.where( res2 >= threshold)

    count=0
    ###Draw rectangles around each instance in the image
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + wr, pt[1] + hr), (0,0,255), 1)
        pp.pprint(pt)
        count+=1
    print(count)
    for pt in zip(*loc1[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + wl, pt[1] + hl), (0,255,0), 1)
    for pt in zip(*loc2[::-1]):
        cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + ws, pt[1] + hs), (255,0,0), 1)
    ###Save the image
    cv2.imwrite('arrow_extracted.jpg',image)
```

Expected result according to above image is 2.
Actual result is 63.
[image: Arrows_extracted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality you have found 63 matching boxes, because they exist. The reason for that is overlapping boxes, You can see the width of drawing a single line and compare it to the width of your bounding boxes to find that there are multiple boxes there. Now can we rectify this, short answer Yes, one way would be to increase the threshold, but I won't recommend that, since you might miss some arrows, we can go with `cv2.minMaxLoc()` but that can only detect one occurrence. `tl;dr;` The best we can do is an Algorithm called non-max suppression.

In short it takes all the boxes and compares if they overlap more than a given threshold area and then suppresses the boxes that overlap too much that they may be bounding the same object.

The code for that can be found on this [git repository](https://github.com/bruceyang2012/nms_python/blob/master/nms.py). and it's explanation is available in [this post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/).

Comment down below if you fail to follow.

Comment: Thank you for he explanation.It made sense.  I will try the above algorithm and get back.